# Graph of the optimal spanning trees of a complete weighted graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given a complete weighted graph $G(V,E);\ E=\lbrace\lbrace u,v\rbrace\,|\,u,v\in V\rbrace$, the set $\mathbb{T}$ of the spanning trees of $G$ is the disjoint union of sets of spanning trees, whose underlying unlabeled topological graphs are isomorphic; these sets shall be denoted by $\mathcal{T_i}$ where the index refers to some enumeration of the set of non-isomorphic unlabeled spanning trees of $G$.

**Question:**

what is known about the connectivity of graph $H$, whose vertices are the optimal elements of $\lbrace\mathcal{T}_i\rbrace$, i.e. the optimal elements from the sets of isomorphic spanning trees of $G$, if the edges of $H$ resemble pairs of these optimal spanning trees, whose union of edges contains exactly one cycle.
The question boils down to as to whether these optimal spanning trees are mutually reachable by a series of edge-swaps that resemble transitons between non-isomorphic optimal spanning trees of $G$ or put the opposite way, whether there are pairs of these optimal spanning trees that are only reachable via sequences of edge-swaps that also contain non-optimal spanning trees with an "intermediate" topology.